# Conditional rendering in cycle.js with RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, jsx, rxjs5

I have a pretty simple conditional rendering scenario where if `props.showCalc` is true, I will render the `calculator`, but if false, I will render the `title`:

```
function view(sources) {
  const props$ = sources.props
  const titleVDom$ = Title(sources).DOM
  const calcVDom$ = Calculator(sources).DOM
  const vdom$ = props$
    .map((props) =>
      <section className="hero is-fullheight is-primary">
        <div className="hero-head">
        </div>
        <div className="hero-body">
          {props.showCalc ? {calcVDom$} : {titleVDom$}}
        </div>
        <div className="hero-foot">
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  return vdom$
}
```

This doesn't work, because you can't pass a stream DOM to JSX to render. I've always had to map the stream DOM in order to render it.

How could I render the `{calcVDom$}` or `{titleVDom$}` in this scenario? As is, they both render "undefined" because they are streams.

I tried to map `calcVDom$`/`titleVDom$` halfway down the render function but it was becoming really messy.

Comment: a runable demo may attract more people willing to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could chain the streams and merge the results before mapping them to the JSX? Something like

```
function view(sources) {

  const props$ = sources.props;
  const titleVDom$ = Title(sources).DOM;
  const calcVDom$ = Calculator(sources).DOM;

  const vdom$ = props$
    .mergeMap((props) => titleVDom$.map((title) => [ props, title ]))
    .mergeMap((data) => calcVDom$.map((calc) => data.push(calc)))
    .map((data) =>
      <section className="hero is-fullheight is-primary">
      <div className="hero-head">
      </div>
      <div className="hero-body">
        {data[0].showCalc ? {data[2]} : {data[1]}}
      </div>
      <div className="hero-foot">
      </div>
    </section>
  );

  return vdom$;
}
```

You could also achieve the same thing using `forkJoin`:

```
function view(sources) {

  const props$ = sources.props;
  const titleVDom$ = Title(sources).DOM;
  const calcVDom$ = Calculator(sources).DOM;

  return Rx.Observable.forkJoin([
    props$,
    titleVDom$,
    calcVDom$
  ]).map((data) =>
      <section className="hero is-fullheight is-primary">
      <div className="hero-head">
      </div>
      <div className="hero-body">
        {data[0].showCalc ? {data[2]} : {data[1]}}
      </div>
      <div className="hero-foot">
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

The difference being that forkJoin will subscribe to all of the Observables (triggering any action) simultaneously while the mergeMap method will chain them, only triggering the second and third when (and if) the preceding ones have emitted a value.